# Четное число в javascript делится на другое число без остатка

Tags: javascript

Есть некий промежуток, который задается через prompt. Для этого промежутка нужно вывести все четные числа, которые делятся без остатка на 3.
Как прописать в if второе условие, что "i % 3 == 0" ?

```js
for (i = firstNumber; i <= secondNumber; i++)
if (i % 2 == 0) {
alert (i);
}
```

Comment: `if (i % 6 == 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```